# How to get ASE (App Service Environment)'s Allow TLS 1.0 and 1.1 enabled or disabled in Az PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

[image: picture for context]

I am trying to find a method to construct a query that will yield the status, either 'On' or 'Off', of the 'Allow TLS 1.0 TLS 1.1' settings.

Comment: The industry in 2015 decided to make SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 obsolete because they were prone to hackers attack.  Microsoft after 5 years did a security push to disable these protocols on windows servers.  Do you really want to enable these protocols?

Answer (score 0):

> To get ASE (App Service Environment)'s Allow TLS 1.0 and 1.1 enabled or disabled in Az PowerShell:

You can obtain all of an app service environment's current `Tls1_0, Tls1_1` settings and then set the `Tls1_0, Tls1_1` to `true` to enable it.

```
$webapp=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -ResourceName "newenv" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments
$webapp.properties
$AllowTls10 = $webapp.Properties.enableTls1_0
$AllowTls11 = $webapp.Properties.enableTls1_1
```

[image]

[image]

Because I lack the appropriate permissions to enable those settings, I tried to use the `hasLinuxWorkers` field in the same manner as described above for `TLS` and it worked as expected.

```
$webapp.Properties.hasLinuxworkers = "true"
$webapp | Set-AzResource -Force
```

[image]

Comment: im not to sure if there is property I can pull named enableTls1_0 or enableTls1_1 within the App service environment. Can you be more clear on what the output will look like if there is

Comment: If there is..? @TeddyMengesha

Comment: $webapp=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "xxxxx" -ResourceName "ASE" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments
$AllowTls10 = $webapp.Properties.enableTls1_0
$AllowTls11 = $webapp.Properties.enableTls1_1

# Output the current settings
Write-Output "AllowTls10: $AllowTls10"
Write-Output "AllowTls11: $AllowTls11"

The output is nothing, I'm saying enableTls1_0 and enableTls1_1 might not be a property. If it is, can you provide me a more clear example. Thank you

Comment: There is no specific property assigned for enabling TLS1. If you want to enable/disable it, you need to retrieve it using properties field. @TeddyMengesha

Comment: Yes but how can I retrieve the tls1 setting. The ASE enableTls1_0 and enableTls1_1 property does not exist. Or maybe it does? need help retrieving it

Comment: The only way is to retrieve all the properties first as I mentioned in the above answer. Otherwise, it is not possible using Azure PowerShell. @TeddyMengesha